# How to set material Shading Type ( Blinn, Physically Based etc) programmatically while using SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am unable to find an example how to set material Shading Type ( Blinn, Physically  Base etc) programmatically in SceneKit with Swift.

I can do it with Xcode but I want to use the same geometry with different shading properties. I don't want to create multiple geometries for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically this is done using the [`lightingModel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462518-lightingmodel) property.